# In pandas, is there a way to add a new column to a dataframe based on a merge with 2 keys without having to make a copy?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very big pandas dataframe (with many columns) and I cannot afford to make a whole copy or I'll run out of memory.
What I need is to create a new column based on a merge by 2 keys. Let me use an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(10,10))
).assign(lab1=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], lab2=[1,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"lab1": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], "lab2": [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], "new_col": np.arange(9)}
)
```

I need to add `new_col` to df, I could do it with a merge...

```
df = df.merge(df2, how="left", on=["lab1", "lab2"], validate="m:1")
```

...but this basically copies the whole dataframe and I run out of memory.

I know that if the merge was only a 1 key merge I could do it without a copy, here is the code:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"lab1": [1,2,3], "new_col2": np.arange(3)})
df["new_col2"] = df.lab1.map(df3.set_index("lab1").new_col2)
```

This does not require to copy `df`. Is there a way to do something like that with 2 keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try `copy=False` option of the `merge` method, which avoids copying when possible.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.random(size=(10,10))
).assign(lab1=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], lab2=[1,2,3,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"lab1": [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], "lab2": [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], "new_col": np.arange(9)}
)

df.merge(df2, how="left", on=["lab1", "lab2"], validate="m:1", copy=False)
```

If that does not work, you can do something like below to implement the merge manually.

```py
mapping = {(l1, l2): v for l1, l2, v in zip(df2.lab1, df2.lab2, df2.new_col)}
df["new_col"] = df.apply(lambda row: mapping.get((row.lab1, row.lab2), None), axis=1)
```